# Cant POST form data with httpclient

Tags: java, android, forms, post

I have a webpage which accepts a roll number and then outputs the result in the same page. The website page source is something like this :

```
 <FORM name="new" ACTION=vitavi.php METHOD=POST >
 <P>Enter the University Seat No: <INPUT TYPE=TEXT NAME="rid" SIZE=20 MAXLENGTH=50><BR><BR><BR><BR>
 <INPUT TYPE=SUBMIT NAME="submit" VALUE="SUBMIT" ALIGN = "center">
```

I have tried to use the post method to fetch the result.

Here 's my code

```
 public String makeServiceCall(String url, int method,
        List<NameValuePair> params) {
    Log.e("Called", "New Called");
    try {
        // http client
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpEntity httpEntity = null;
        HttpResponse httpResponse = null;

        // Checking http request method type
        if (method == POST) {
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            // adding post params
            if (params != null) {
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
                Log.e("Called", "This called");
            }

            httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);


        } else if (method == GET) {
            // appending params to url
            if (params != null) {
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils
                        .format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
            }
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url); 
            httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet); 
        }
        httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        response = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
       // Log.e("Hiiii",response);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

And I have added the params in MainActivity like this :

```
  final Httpcall res=new Httpcall();
                    final List<NameValuePair> param=new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                    param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("rid", r));
                    new Thread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            HtmlStr=res.makeServiceCall("http://results.vtu.ac.in/vitavi.php",Httpcall.POST, param);
```

But everytime the page that is first page i.e, the one which accepts the roll no is bieng shown. Where am I going wrong ?

Thanks in advance .

Comment: I dont like the way you write your html. ;(

Comment: Actually I didnt write this HTML @DegenSharew . I am just writing an app that fetches the page of this page.

Comment: ok. but I did not get your question. "..the one which accepts the roll no is bieng accepted. "

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem now . Posting this answer so that anybody facing the same problem wont have to wait as I had to:

I didnt know that we have to also add a  BasicNameValuePair for the Submit Button.

```
<INPUT TYPE=SUBMIT NAME="submit" VALUE="SUBMIT" ALIGN = "center">
```

So after adding the roll number I added another pair:

```
param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("rid", r));
param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("submit", "SUBMIT"));
```